# Why is the appBar font weight more than in the body

Tags: windows, flutter, dart, fonts, appbar

When I try to run my Flutter app (on windows), I see that the appBar title weight is more than the body text weight (even though they're the same font)

[This is what I mean - the appBar weight is more than the weight of the text on the body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPHVQ.png)

My code looks like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'SegoeUIVar'),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Hello World',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(32.0),
          child: AppBar(
            elevation: 0,
            backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(230, 30, 31, 28),
            centerTitle: true,
            title: const Text("Hello World", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15, fontFamily: 'SegoeUIVar')),
          )
        ),

        body: const Center(
          child: Text('Hello World'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In flutter each widget has its own theme, so even if it is assigned a different fontFamily, the fontWeight will be default to that widgets theme. To assign the same fontWweight you need to do it in the TextStyle or in the actual theme

```
 Text(
    'Hello',
    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
  ),
)
```

Comment: it could also be the same and the contrast just makes it look different since one is white on black and the other is black on white.